# How to set value in input field in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am a beginner in angular. I am able to make drop down and able to get it value using ng-model. But I need to get different value on input field. If the value of drop down value is blank then input field value is "blank". When drop down value is "one" input filled with "rahul" so I will set these value while checking the value of drop down?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/wVo9SW8Lc0uVr213grR2?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller='cntrl'>
    <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors"></select>
    <button ng-click="getColor()">getvalue</button>
    <input type ="text"/>
  </body>

  <script>
    angular.module('app',[]).controller('cntrl',function($scope){
      $scope.colors=[{name:"one"},{name:"two"},{name:"tree"}]
      $scope.getColor=function(){
        alert('--'+$scope.myColor.name)
      }
    })
  </script>
</html>
```

Is there no way to check value of drop down? Is there any way to check onchange listener in angular? Of is there any if-else condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the [value](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp) of the `input` field to a javascript function using `<input type="text" value="{{getValue()}}">`. The getValue() function can then check the `myColor` variable and return accordingly. I also simplified the model a bit, colors is now an array of strings. When `myColor==="one"`, `getValue` returns "rahul" which populates the input, else it returns "";

See: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hNuuXiOL6fGO8Odrw5VS?p=preview)

Comment: great answer ...!!! thanks but there is problem in your it call two time http://plnkr.co/edit/lgBcLP2yEGTk172QnPi8?p=info

Comment: when you change select option it show two time alert

Comment: If you need it to be called once, you can use `$scope.$watch` to watch the variable and update the variable bound to the input accordingly. See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/f0T2WwAyjJuIZ1tEIb0K?p=preview)